# Centre align leaderboard ad

Tags: html, css, leaderboard

Struggling a little to centrally align a leaderboard ad on [Dots & Dashes](http://dotsanddashes.co.uk) – positions itself correctly on certain pages, and incorrectly on several others, by the seems of it.

Have applied the `<div class="center">AD CODE</div>` tag, although that doesn't seem to have done the trick...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as per always!
Thanks.

Comment: Don't link to your resources (that might change or die in the future)- instead, post the relevant parts of your code here so we can help you faster and will serve as an archive for future users to refer back to.

Comment: Apologies – will do in future...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean center horizontally or vertically?

To center horizontally you can add the following to the top of the page (within the `<head></head>` section):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .center {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

The above will control the class that you assigned (center) and adds text-align:center; to it.

If you are looking to center the div vertically, please post a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

To center something horizontally within the DIV use the following code...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .center {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

But to center something horizontally within the WINDOW and DIV, try this....

```
<style type="text/css">
    .center {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Will this not centre all the text on the site, though? I'm literally just looking to centre this troublesome leaderboard...

Comment: No, it will only center those items that you apply the class of 'center'.